# Web App and Database Host on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Hy Guys,
I'm new to Asp.net and Azure. I was working on ASP.NET with the help of this documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), When I publish my project on Azure by creating the Web App with latest portal on Azure, **but it is only my application host on the Azure. And now i need to publish the my project database to Azure**. In the present portal, the database option is not present there when we create the Web App on Azure to host the database as well with the Web project. But in the old portal as the documentation link guides us the database option is also present there when we publish our Web project on Azure. 
**Can anyone explain me how can i deploy my Web App existing database to Azure even if my Project has been deployed on Azure?**

Comment: Exactly what are you trying that isn't working? Your question is way to vague

Comment: **How can I deploy my existing Web App Database to Azure on the new portal.**

Answer (score 2):

> How can I deploy my existing Web App Database to Azure on the new portal.

If you use Code First Model of Entity Framework, you could just configure the connection string for your web application when you publish your web application. Entity Framework will generate tables for you automatically.

If there are existing data in your database which you want to migrate to Azure SQL Database. You could download a tool named [Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) which will help you do it.  For detail steps, link below is for your reference.

[SQL Server database migration to SQL Database in the cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate)

> In the documentation he is using the old dashboard of Azure in which database option is attached with the Web App Publish procedure.

A small difference between old dashboard and new dashboard is that the creating Azure SQL Database feature is hidden when you create your app service. You need to click Explorer additional Azure services link to open the a new window for creating Azure SQL Database.

[image]

[image]

After creating a database, you could choose the database in the Setting tab when you publish your web application.

You also could create a database directly in Azure portal. After creating a database, you could get the connection string from the overview page.

> If you make changes to a database schema and are using code first EF, will EF update your database schema when you redeploy your web app?

It depends whether you have enabled and run  the migration. In the publish setting window, we could click the [Execute Code First Migrations] button  to update the database schema .

[image]

If this button is disabled in the setting window, we need to run Enable-Migrations command in Package Manager Console.

In Visual Studio click  menu Tool -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console, input Enable-Migrations and run it.

Comment: Your Answer is so much helpful 2 me. But dear this is the procedure at the start when we create the application in Visual Studio and We've selected **Host in the Cloud**. But if you have not select it, the project is created now you wanna publish it then just application has been deployed on Azure. There isn't any option to deploy the database to Azure as well.

Comment: My Problem has been Solved Dear through this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dp-DT4iZ5-8)

Comment: Nice answer, Amor. I have a follow-up question. If you make changes to a database schema and are using code first EF, will EF udpate your database schema when you redeploy your web app? I do not think that it does.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have further question, please feel free to let me know.